# Chrome tabs auto refreshing everytime on desktop

Tags: google-chrome

The chrome tabs auto refreshes every time when I go to the tab and its turning out to be really annoying. Any fix?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this inside Chrome Version 48.0 (Running on Windows 7) by performing the following steps.

1.) Open the Chrome browser and navigate to chrome://flags 
2.) Search on the page for "Enable tab discarding" 
3.) Set this flag to "Disabled" 
4.) Restart Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will do that when you are low on memory. If you have a lot of programs open, try closing some of them out.

Comment: I have only chrome open and that still happens. I open around 10-12 tabs. It never happened before though.